# Stability of difference equation considering only positive values

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I'm analyzing the stability of such system difference equation with the constraint that $y_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \geq 0$ :

$y_n = B y_{n-1} + D y_{n-2} \enspace (1)$

Using variable transform, the above system can be transformed to:

$z_n = L z_{n-1}$

where

$L = \left(\begin{matrix}B & D\\ I&0\end{matrix}\right)$,

and $z_{n} = \left(\begin{matrix}y_n \\ y_{n-1} \end{matrix}\right)$

I can analyze the stability of system (1) depending on the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $L$.

BUT, eigenvalues do not consider the strong constraint $y_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \geq 0$. How this constraint could be integrated in the stability analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, too.  This approach works for me.  I hope it is of some help.

**Solve the system:**
This is a relatively simple equation; I can use it to figure out how to relate the system to the matrix.

Say we have some initial values, $\;y_{-2}\! = k_2/D, \;\; y_{-1} \!\!= k_1,\;$ so that
$$y_0 = Bk_1 + k_2$$
Then$$y_1 = (B^2+D)k_1 + Bk_2\\
y_2 = (B^3+2BD)k_1 + (B^2 + D)k_2\\
y_3 = (B^4+3B^2D + D^2)k_1 + (B^3 + 2BD)k_2\\
...$$
Setting $y_{-2}\!\! = k_2$ gets there, too.  Now I want to show that
 $$ y_n = P_n k_1 + P_{n-1} k_2$$
That is, the coefficient $P_n$ of $k_1$ in $y_n$, it also the coefficient of $k_2$ in $y_{n+1}$.  The system is determined by a single polynomial sequence.

$k_1$ and $k_2$ are arbitrary initial values (!scalar parameters!) which must satisfy the linear system $\;P_n k_1 + P_{n-1}k_2 \ge 0\;\; \forall n \ge 0.$

But we can represent a polynomial p<sub>A</sub> as, say, $\;p_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I-A)$.  And I can also, if I wish, write $k_1$ in the form $a k_2 D + b$.

Now consider the given

**Conditions:**
  B party!  If $|B|>1$, there is some $n$ past which the sum $y_n$, (and therefore its sign), is dominated by the term $B^{n+1}$, irrespective of the other initial values.  This term alternates even/odd powers, so we have the pair of conditions,
$\;\;\;B \ge 0,$
$\;\;\;B>1 \implies k_1 >0.$
In a similar way, we can shake more conditions out.

Depending on what's left, we probably want *at least* $\;y_n \ge 0 \implies y_{n+1} \ge 0$. While I'm stuck, I work the slow way (regular algebra) and then figure out how to abstract.  Takes longer at first, but then I know what I'm up to.

Lastly, I find strong conditions make it easier to characterize a system. Break the conditions, hem in the solution.  IMO, breaking "Positive for all n" is a good plan of attack for figuring out how to satisfy it.

Hope that helps.

---

I read this as a question about process. Let me know if I should finish the problem.